# Ordering soups in a restaurant

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

A restaurant serves $10$ different varieties of soup one of which is mushroom soup. In how many ways can we order six plates of soup if (a) exactly four plates must be mushroom soup (b) at least four plates must be mushroom soup.

Based on my understanding, in this problem repetition is allowed and we have to apply combinations in distinguishable items. I applied the following formula: $^{n+r-1}C_{r}$.

For (a), my answer is: $^{9+2-1}C_{2-1}= 10$.

 For (b), my answer is: $^{10+2-1}C_{2-1} = 11$.

Did I get the correct answers?

Comment: No - that is not correct: if four of the six plates are mushroom, then the other two have more than $11$ possibilities.  Does your order of mushroom soup and my order of onion soup  count as the same way as my order of mushroom soup and your order of onion soup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstood stars and bars and the application of your $^{n+r-1}C_{r}$ formula.

For part A you have $n=10-1=9$ and $r=6-4=2$ to give $^{10}C_{2} = 45$

For part B you have $n=10-1=9$ and $r=2,1,0$ to give $^{10}C_{2} +\;^{9}C_{1} +\;^{8}C_{0} = 55$

You would get far higher numbers if the order of the orders mattered, for example if your order of mushroom soup and my order of onion soup count as distinct from my order of mushroom soup and your order of onion soup:

For part A you would have $^{6}C_{4}\times 9^2 =1215$

For part B you would have $^{6}C_{4}\times 9^2 +\;^{6}C_{5}\times 9^1 +\;^{6}C_{6}\times 9^0  =1215+54+1=1270$

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This assumes the order in which the soup is bought is of no importance (not specified in the question.) Also I have changed the erroneous ${}_{2+9-1}\mathrm{C}_{2-1}$ to the correct ${}_{2+9-1}\mathrm{C}_{9-1}$.

Part A:

We don't get to pick the flavors for the first four bowls of soup, so they don't need to be considered. For the remaining $2$ bowls of soup, we can choose every flavor *except* mushroom, since we need to have **exactly** four bowls of mushroom soup. That means we have $10-1=9$ choices for each of the remaining $2$ bowls of soup. Based on **stars and bars**, which is beautifully explained in [this Numberphile video](https://youtu.be/UTCScjoPymA), we can say that the number of ways to select two bowls of soup with $9$ choices for each is
$$\# \text{ of ways (4 mushroom)}= {}_{2+9-1}\mathrm{C}_{9-1}={}_{10}\mathrm{C}_8=45.$$

Part B:

For this question it's actually easier to count how many ways we can order soup with exactly $4,5$, and $6$ bowls of mushroom soup individually. That is,
$$\# \text{ of ways }(\geq 4\text{ mushroom)}$$
$$=\# \text{ of ways (4 mushroom)}+\# \text{ of ways (5 mushroom)}+\# \text{ of ways (6 mushroom)}$$
It's obvious that the number of ways to order exactly one bowl of non-mushroom soup is $9$ and there is only one way of ordering $6$ bowls of mushroom soup. So,
$$\# \text{ of ways }(\geq 4\text{ mushroom)}=45+9+1=55$$

Comment: 10 looks too small for part A

Comment: @Henry If we only care about which soups are ordered, this answer is correct.  If we care who receives which bowl of soup, then it is too small.

Comment: Reading the problem, I am not sure whether it's asking to count which soups are ordered or who receives which bowl of soup. @N. F. Taussig

Comment: @N.F.Taussig If ${9 \choose 1}=9$ is correct when there is exactly one bowl of non-mushroom soup, then the number when there are exactly two bowls of non-mushroom soup will be higher than $10$, and presumably would be ${10 \choose 2}=45$

Comment: @Henry If the answer the first problem is 10C2, then shouldn't the answer for the second problem be: 10C2 + 9C1 + 8C0 = 55?

Comment: @Scott - yes - see my alternative answer

Comment: @Henry  Yes, I forgot that $2$ was the number of bowls.

Comment: The question is phrased to sound like one person is getting all six bowls of soup. I didn't know that the order in which the soup is bought mattered. This was not specified in the question.

Comment: @Henry Indeed a small calculation mistake. I plugged in "$n$" instead of "$k$" into the formula. Corrected now.